# How can I even out a set of uneven vertices to form a vertical surface?

Tags: modeling, mesh, vertices

Hey so I'm a Blender newbie who figured out that somewhere during my modelling, I got some parts uneven as seen on this picture from the side:

[image: Uneven wall]
 .

That vertical part is supposed to be 90 degrees straight. It consists of several vertices. **How can I straighten out these vertices to form a shape parallel to the z axis, completely vertical?

Comment: Try Scaling to 0. 1. Select vertices 2. Press `S X 0`, where X is the axis to flatten on.

Comment: Gandalf3's advice seems to be spot on, and though he noted that it can be used with any axis, he may just have muddied the waters a a bit by using X as a variable. Scaling a set of vertices constraining the scaling to any one of the axes, x, y, or z, will align the vertices parallel to that axis. You may be more precise in your modeling than I, but I always find it expedient, if I want to scale vertices to a line parallel to the z axis, as in the case of the illustration, to scale the relevant points not only to the X axis, but also to the Y axis, and viewing the result from more than one POV.